# scroll page with settimeout - i need add a settimeout or delay to my code

Tags: javascript, function, scroll, settimeout, scrolltop

i need insert a settimeout to give the user time to see the "home" . Then scroll (scrollTo) the content of the web to div Automatically . Unless the user has already scroller

```
     $(document).ready(function (){
        $(window).ready(function (){
            $('html, body').animate({
                scrollTop: $("#hola").offset().top
            }, 5000);
        });
        $("html, body").bind("scroll mousedown DOMMouseScroll mousewheel keyup", function(){
$('html, body').stop();
```

Comment: Please explain why you can't and what you're trying to do...

Comment: Sorry! i need insert a settimeout to give the user time to see the "home" . Then scroll the content of the web Automatically . Unless the user has already scroller

Answer (score 0):

Save users mouse position and using setInterval check for every 3 seconds if mouse position changed  - if it did just save new mouse position otherwise just scroll . ( I hope you have your scrolling logic already ? )

Comment: i need insert a settimeout to give the user time to see the "home" . Then scroll the content of the web Automatically . Unless the user has already scroller .

Comment: This wont scroll for 3 seconds if he will not move with mouse and will stay forever if using mouse constantly.